# Security - Android app to permit offline login only when a valid online login has occured prior

Tags: android, authentication

I have an app i'm developing that requires users to be able to use it when offline (remote locations). The goal is to have a login that requires a user to authenticate. If online, authentication will use oauth tokens. But, if offline, no token validation can occur. So, i want to permit the user to authenticate using locally stored info.

Proposal:

1. request correct credentials -> user enters username & password
2. if online, proceed with oauth tokens,

   a. if successful, store AES encrypted username/password + salts
   b. if unsuccessful, re-request correct credentials
3. if offline, using same encryption as above, encrypt the username/password combination
4. test offline encrypted credentials against list of recent successful online logins saved in step 2a.
   a. if creds match one of the saved versions, access to app and local data in offline mode
   b. if creds fail to match, re-request correct creds

**Question**:
Will storing locally encrypted combo un+pw+salt compromise security of the online login process? Further thoughts/advice?

Thanks for participating.

Comment: In two words it will get compromised theoretically but having a good enc algorithm makes it close to impossible to decrypt it practically. Remember the windows domains and localhost account? If there's no network connection it would still let you in. As well as all the unix systems they can check you against different auth services but still have /etc/shadow or /etc/master.password with encrypted passwords....

Comment: Just get a good encryption algorithm and be done with it :)))

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement is possible with Shared Preferences only

```
public class MySession {
    private SharedPreferences sharedPref;
    private static Editor editor;

    public static final String My_API_KEY = "1234";
    public static final String My_CLIENT_VERSION = "1.0";
    private static final String My_API_TOKEN = "api_token";
    private static final String My_USER_SCREEN_NAME ="profilepic";
    private static final String SHARED = "my_Preferences";

    public MySession(Context context) {
        sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedPref.edit();
    }
    public void storeToken(String apiToken) {
        editor.putString(My_API_TOKEN, apiToken);       
        editor.commit();
    }
    public String getToken() {
        return sharedPref.getString(My_API_TOKEN,null);     
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Ask user for login details first time. After authentication concatenate   username and password and make its md5/sha1. Store it in shared preferences or local sqlite db.

Next time while user is offline ask for login details, concat and verify it from same saved place.

sha1/md5 are one way encryption and cannot be decrypted. So login details will always be safe in device.